# Searching for multiple terms in wordpress using SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress, tags

I am trying to write an sql query that will return posts if they match the entire set of terms given:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 

LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS trel ON (wp_posts.ID = trel.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS ttax ON (ttax.taxonomy = 'business-tags' AND trel.term_taxonomy_id = ttax.term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS tter ON (ttax.term_id = tter.term_id)

WHERE 1=1 
AND (tter.slug LIKE '%crazy%' AND tter.slug LIKE '%insane%')  
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'business' 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

I hage a post in the db that has both of those tags. Now if I search for only one tag, I get the result, but when I do multiple tags, it returns a zero result. Any advice on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I get the feeling I am checking to see if the slug is both 'crazy' and 'insane', but if that's the case, do I need to do a left join for every tag?

Comment: You got it in one, that's your problem.  Do you want posts to have _both_ tags, or you only need one of them?  Also, read up on the `HAVING` clause, it's meant for these situations.

Comment: You really shouldn't be prefixing your table names with `wp`, it's (largely) just noise - if your system supports it, separate by schema, if necessary.  Also, what RDBMS?  Here's a (simplified) [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/15adc/10/0) that runs on PostgreSQL.  Putting the `LIKE` condition in the `WHERE` clause is also turning those `LEFT` joins into `INNER` joins - if you don't actually care about existence, you're going to have to move the comparison into the join itself.